# KVO with Run-to-Completion semantics - Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, architecture, key-value-observing, reentrancy

I recently ran into reentrancy issues with KVO. To visualize the problem, I would like to show a minimal example. Consider the interface of an `AppDelegate` class

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) int x;
@end
```

as well as its implementation

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)          application:(__unused UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(__unused NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    __unused BigBugSource *b = [[BigBugSource alloc] initWithAppDelegate:self];

    self.x = 42;
    NSLog(@"%d", self.x);

   return YES;
}

@end
```

Unexpectedly, this program prints **43** to the console.

Here's why:

```
@interface BigBugSource : NSObject {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
@end

@implementation BigBugSource

- (id)initWithAppDelegate:(AppDelegate *)anAppDelegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        appDelegate = anAppDelegate;
        [anAppDelegate addObserver:self 
                        forKeyPath:@"x" 
                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                           context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [appDelegate removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"x"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(__unused NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(__unused id)object
                        change:(__unused NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(__unused void *)context
{
    if (appDelegate.x == 42) {
        appDelegate.x++;
    }
}

@end
```

As you see, some different class (that may be in third-party code you do not have access to) may register an invisible observer to a property. This observer is then called synchronously, whenever the property's value has changed.

Because the call happens during the execution of another function, this introduces all sort of concurrency / multithreading bugs although the program runs on a single thread. Worse, the change happens without an explicit notice in the client-code (OK, you could expect that concurrency issues arise whenever you set a property...).

What is the best practice to solve this problem in Objective-C?

- Is there some common solution to regain run-to-completion semantics automatically, meaning that KVO-Observation messages go through an event-queue, AFTER the current method finishes executing and invariants / postconditions are restored?
- Not exposing any properties?
- Guarding every critical function of an object with a boolean variable to ensure that reentrancy is not possible?
  For example: `assert(!opInProgress); opInProgress = YES;` at the beginning of the methods, and `opInProgress = NO;` at the end of the methods. This would at least reveal those kind of bugs directly during runtime.
- Or is it possible to opt out of KVO somehow?

**Update**

Based on the answer by CRD, here is the updated code:

`BigBugSource`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(__unused NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(__unused id)object
                        change:(__unused NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(__unused void *)context
{
    if (appDelegate.x == 42) {
        [appDelegate willChangeValueForKey:@"x"]; // << Easily forgotten
        appDelegate.x++;                          // Also requires knowledge of
        [appDelegate didChangeValueForKey:@"x"];  // whether or not appDelegate  
    }                                             // has automatic notifications
}
```

`AppDelegate`

```
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"x"]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return [super automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:key];
    }
}

- (BOOL)          application:(__unused UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(__unused NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    __unused BigBugSource *b = [[BigBugSource alloc] initWithAppDelegate:self];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"x"];
    self.x = 42;
    NSLog(@"%d", self.x);    // now prints 42 correctly
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"x"];
    NSLog(@"%d", self.x);    // prints 43, that's ok because one can assume that
                             // state changes after a "didChangeValueForKey"
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is manual change notification and is supported by KVO. It is a three stage process:

1. Your class overrides `+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString *)theKey` returning `NO` for any property you wish to defer notifications for and deferring to `super` otherwise;
2. Before changing a property you call `[self willChangeValueForKey:key]`; and
3. When you are ready for the notification to occur you call `[self didChangeValueForKey:key]`

You can build on this protocol quite easily, e.g. it is easy to keep a record of keys you have changed and trigger them all before you exit.

You can also use `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey` with automatic notifications turned *on* if you directly alter the backing variable of a property and need to trigger KVO.

The process along with an examples is described in Apple's [documentation](http://tinyurl.com/8gce9d9).

Comment: This improves the situation already. However, there are still issues. Consider a situation where you have a class that is part of a third-party library and that uses automatic notifications. When you change a property of an instance of this class, reentrancy problems arise again if another object has registered itself as an observer. The second problem is that you also have to call `willChange` and `didChange` if you change a property from outside, making code error-prone because it is easily forgotten. Is there no solution for this that truly supports run-to-completion semantics?

Comment: @Etan - for third-party code you really have to leave it to them to behave as they see fit. For your code with a little work you can hold notifications for a particular class until you release them - turning off automatic notifications and adding `will/didChange` to your setters gets you back to the equivalent of automatic notification; however if you now add a flag (use a property, say 1holdNotifications`, to (un)set it) which when set causes your setters to queue the willChange, and when unset fires off any queued willChange's you've got the semantics I think you are after.